# Why color of dress changes when water falls?

Tags: visible-light, water

When you drop water to dress actually the color changes, that is the color of dress becomes dark, but when you add water to color, for example water color or poster color it becomes light. Why is it so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why wet is dark?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30366/)