# Colour of a wet T-shirt

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, material-science, reflection

Why does a light grey T-shirt look dark grey when wet?
I think this happens because the water molecules get stuck in the fabric and reflect light in different ways(different wavelengths) compared to the reflection that occurs when the cloth is not wet. 
Is this right or are there other reasons?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30366/2451 and links therein.