# Why do some objects become transparent while others dark when water is absorbed by them?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, water, wetting

When water is absorbed by soil for example, it gets dark. But when water is absorbed by tissue paper, and kept closer to another object, that object can be seen pretty clearly through the tissue paper.
Isn't it possible that soil becomes translucent and the tissue paper becomes darker in colour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do wet objects become darker?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30366/)