# Why is wet paper transparent?

Tags: everyday-life

When paper get wet, it becomes transparent. How does this happen? Is it because of refraction, or bcause water extends the space between molecules that consist of the paper? I have no clue.

Comment: Related: [Why wet is dark?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30366/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does paper become translucent when smeared with oil but not (so much) with water?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30365/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paper is opaque because there are mineral fillers in between the cellulose fibers, which are in a crystalline form. When surrounded by air, they appear opaque due to the higher difference in the index of refraction between the two. When wet, the paper appears translucent because there is a lower difference in the index of refraction between the crystals and the water, making it translucent.